# id as ng-model for select in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am not getting the id value of the option value of selected item of  tag.

```
<div ng-controller="UserCreationCtrl">
    <form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputFirstName">First name:</label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputFirstName" ng-model="doctor.firstName" placeholder="First name"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span  class="nullable">
                <select ng-model="user.lookupId" ng-options="select as speciality.lookupName for speciality in specialityList" ng-change="selectedSpecilaty()">
                    <option value="">-- choose speciality --</option>
                </select>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My controller

```
app.controller('UserCreationCtrl', ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {

    $scope.specialityList = [
                                 {lookupId : 1, lookupName: 'speciality1'},
                                 {lookupId : 2, lookupName: 'speciality2'},

                                 {lookupId : 4, lookupName: 'speciality6'},
                                 {lookupId : 3, lookupName: 'speciality3'}
                                 ];

    $scope.user = {firstName: 'first name value', lookupId : 4};

    $scope.selectedSpecilaty = function()
    {
        alert($scope.user.lookupId);
    }
}]);
```

How can i do this. the alert box displying the value as 'undefined'.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ng-options` patterns can be confusing to get started with, as there are quite a bunch.

What you wrote right now means:

```
select     as     speciality.lookupName    for   speciality   in   specialityList
 ^-- the value to set to   ^-- what to display      ^-- iteree name  ^-- iterables
```

So the variables you have available in the expression are everythin you have defined on the scope, and the contextual `specialty` variable. When you select something it'll assign it to `select`, which is indeed `undefined`.

What you're looking for is

```
ng-options="speciality.lookupId as speciality.lookupName for speciality in specialityList"
```

This will set the value of what `ng-model` is pointing to to the contextual `specialty`'s `lookupId`

Comment: In my case (Angular 1.2.15) I had the expression right, but I was using the "track by" expression at the end unnecessarily, which apparently breaks it and causes the model to track the entire object rather than the value/ID you're selecting. This is partly due to missing documentation and possibly corrected in newer versions of Angular; see the GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564.

Comment: The official documentation on ngOptions is very unclear about the use of `as` to define the value being set on ngModel. Thanks for making thinks more clear bro! :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the `select` key that refers to the `value` key specified in your `ng-options`. Since your `value` key is **speciality** then to bind `user.lookupId` to your `ng-model` with the currently selected option's `lookupId`, you have to change **select** to **specialty.lookupId**

So your **[select's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)** `ng-options` should be:

```
<select ng-model="user.lookupId" ng-options="speciality.lookupId as speciality.lookupName for speciality in specialityList" ng-change="selectedSpecilaty()">
  <option value="">-- choose speciality --</option>
</select>
```